# Passing dataframe to keras sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to build and train a simple MLP model using keras.Sequential().
However, I'm having issues when, after each training epoch, I try to evaluate the current status of the model on the train and test data.

I'm having this problem on a couple different datasets, one of them is the "CAR DETAILS FROM CAR DEKHO" dataset, you can find it [here](https://www.kaggle.com/nehalbirla/vehicle-dataset-from-cardekho?select=CAR%20DETAILS%20FROM%20CAR%20DEKHO.csv)

This is what I'm doing so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

def main()

    ## read, preprocess and split data
    df_data = pd.read_csv('car_data_CAR_DEKHO.csv')
    df_data = pre_process(df_data)
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = split_data(df_data)  ## -> these are PANDAS DATAFRAMES!


    train(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)


def train(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):

    ##--------------------
    ##   building model
    ##--------------------
    batch = 5000
    epochs = 500
    lr = 0.001


    data_iter = load_array((X_train, y_train), batch)


    initializer = tf.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.01)
    net = tf.keras.Sequential()
    net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer))
    loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    trainer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr)


    ##--------------#
    ##   training   #
    ##--------------#
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        for X_batch, Y_batch in data_iter:
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                l = loss(net(X_batch, training=True), Y_batch)
            grads = tape.gradient(l, net.trainable_variables)
            trainer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, net.trainable_variables))


        # test on train set after epoch
        y_pred_train = net(X_train)    ## ERROR HERE!!!
        l_train = loss(y_pred_train, y_train)
        y_pred_test = net(X_test)
        l_test = loss(y_pred_test, y_test)


def load_array(data_arrays, batch_size, is_train=True):
    """Construct a TensorFlow data iterator."""
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_arrays)
    if is_train:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

def split_data(df_data):
    X = df_data.copy()
    y = X.pop('selling_price')
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

def pre_process(df_data):
    ## check NaNs and drop rows if any
    print(df_data.isnull().sum())
    df_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    ## drop weird outlier, turns out it has 1 km_driven
    df_data.drop([1312], inplace=True)

    ## features engineering
    df_data['name'] = df_data['name'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
    df_data['owner'] = df_data['owner'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
    df_data['selling_price'] = df_data['selling_price']/1000
    df_data_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_data, drop_first=True)
    df_data_dummies = normalize(df_data_dummies)  ## this is a simple min-max scaling, I do it manually but you can use sklearn or something similar
    return df_data_dummies


def normalize(df):
    print('Data normalization:')
    result = df.copy()
    for feature_name in df.columns:
        if feature_name == 'selling_prize':
            pass
        else:
            max_value = df[feature_name].max()
            min_value = df[feature_name].min()
            result[feature_name] = (df[feature_name] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
            if result[feature_name].isnull().values.any():
                result.drop([feature_name], axis=1, inplace=True)
                print(f'Something wrong in {feature_name}, dropped.')
                print(f'now shape is {len(result)}, {len(result.columns)}')
    print(f'\treturning {len(result)}, {len(result.columns)}')
    return result
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
File "/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
    ndim = x.shape.rank
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

I guess the error is due to me passing X_train (which is a dataframe) directly to net.

I also tried using again:

```
y_pred_train = net(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train))
```

like when creating training batches, but it returns another error:

```
    File "/home/lews/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 201, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise TypeError('Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: %s' % (x,))
    TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <TensorSliceDataset shapes: (19,), types: tf.float64>
```

Finally, I tried using:

```
y_pred_train = net.predict(X_train)
```

the weird thing in this case is that I got an OOM error, referring to a tensor with shape[76571,76571]:

```
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[76571,76571] and type double on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu [Op:SquaredDifference]
```

but the X_train datagrame has shape (76571, 19), so I don't understand what is happening.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mostly looks OK, the issue must be with the data that you pass.
Check content and datatypes of the data that you feed.

Try converting pandas slices into np.arrays, re-check their dimensions and then feed np.arrays to load_array().

Also try smaller batches, like 64 (not 5000).

UPDATE:
Apparently when you pass `X_batch` to the model you pass tf.tensor, but later when you pass whole `X_train` or `X_test`  - you pass pd.DataFrames and the model gets confused.

You should change just 2 lines:

```
y_pred_train = net(tf.constant(X_train))  # pass TF.tensor - best

#alternative: 
y_pred_train = net(X_train.values)  # pass np.array - also good

y_pred_test = net(tf.constant(X_test)) # make similar change here
```

Comment: I checked the data, there were no NaNs and the dtype was float64 for everything. I also tried with some other csv files, and I still got the same error. The weird part is that I'm feeding directly X_train to the net when using l = loss(net(X_batch, training=True), Y_batch), and it doesn't return the error. However, I followed you other suggestion and converted X_train, X_test, Y_train and Y_test to numpy (X_train.to_numpy()) and everything's working now. Could it be that I was doing something wrong in generating the data splits? I added that part of the code in the original question.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your dataframe for testing?

Comment: Added the dataset and the rest of my code in the original post

Comment: I updated the answer. Pls accept and upvote if OK.

Comment: to  – @user23657: `net` is defined in the code in the question `net = tf.keras.Sequential()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks like it is related to the data (as Poe Dator says). What I believe is going on is that your network has some input shape based on the batches of data it is receiving. Then when you are trying to predict or call your network on the data (this also recomputes shapes since it calls the build() function), it tries to get the data into the shape it expects. I think specifically it is expecting a shape of (batch, 1, 19) but with your data in (76571, 19) it is not finding the correct shape.

A couple of easy steps to work on this would be:

1. Call net.summary() to see what the shapes it believes it is getting before and after training
2. Provide the input shape to the first layer, net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer, input_shape=(1, 19)))
3. Slice your X data in the same shape as your training data.
4. Add a dimension to your data so it is (76571, 1, 19) to explicitly shape it as well.

Also as noted above, smaller batch sizes would be best. I would also recommend using the model.train() method instead of handling gradients if you don't have a lot of experience with tensorflow. This saves you code and is easier to ensure you are handling your model correctly during training.